# UNC Path for calendar .gif jquery date picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to be able to put a UNC path for the calendar picture here is what I have
and it's not work I have used this with the http path and it works fine but it does not like the unc? anyone Please?

```
 $('.dateField').datepicker({
 showOn:  "button" 
 buttonImage:  "\\10.1.93.95\SymForms\MOProgramming\mo_CSS\images\calendar.gif",
 buttonImageOnly: true
  });
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! For us to help out with your question, we'll need more context: check out the guidelines on [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and include more steps on the code needed to reproduce the problem, the system you're working on, and what you've tried so far (including links to related questions). We'd like to help, but need you to help make this clearer!

Comment: Found the answer I needed  to reverse the slashes or use the back slash instead of the forward slash. (which is generally not the case for UNC paths.